# How can I get the metaclass of a class in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi-7, metaclass

I want to raise an exception like that if an object is missing from the context object attribute list:

```
//******************************************************************************
  EMissingContextObject = class (...)
//******************************************************************************
    private
      // Attributes
      fAttrName : string;
      fAttrType : TClass;

    public
      // Overiden constructors
      constructor create( attrName_ : string; attrType_ : TClass );

      // Properties
      property attrName : string read fAttrName;
      property attrType : TClass read fAttrType;

  end;
//******************************************************************************
```

How can I pass the TClass type of an arbitrary TObject descendant? I know there is the

```
CClassType = class of TClassType;
```

definition but I don't want to depend on this declaration.
I've tried the TObject.classType, but it just works on instances.
I've tried the TypeInfo( TClassType ) but it gives back just the name of the class.
There should be something like in Java:

```
TClass c = TClassType.class;
```

or

```
TClass c = TClass.forName( className );
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `TClass` can already accept any class type, just pass the class type as-is, eg: `Create('attrName', TMyAttrClass);` if that is not doing what you need then please explain your problem better.

Comment: I used PTypeInfo instead, because it is useable for primitive types as well. I just want to declare the missing context attribute in the exception as detailed form as possible.